# Is CiviCRM right for managing volunteers on clinical trials

Tags: civimember, relationships, civivolunteer, community

We need to keeping volunteers happy and engaged in trials. We would need segment our volunteers based on preferences for type of trials they want to participate in, whether they agreed to participate in a trial, rejected it or dropped out of a trial, whether they have completed all/some regular online tests.

That is the basics of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the information you are giving is far too limited to give a true answer if CiviCRM is right.

At the same time I am fairly convinced CiviCRM in combination with probably a Drupal website would support the kind of thing you are roughly sketching. But I recommend you do a prototype project first to establish what CiviCRM + website can do out of the box, what it can not do without customization and how important that is for you etc.

And probably contact a CiviCRM partner in your region to help you with that important first step. You can find an expert in your region here: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors

Answer (score 1):

I see you tagged this as both civimember and civivolunteer. I don't think that either Component would be required based on your initial description.

You could also conceive as a specific trail as an 'event' and hence anyone who signs up for that trail gets attached to the event. Then you can track if they participate, reject, drop out etc by different 'participant types' on the event. It seems like a reasonable match.

From your description the remaining areas should be able to be managed via custom fields on the Contact alongside custom fields on Activities. If you are using Drupal then you can use webforms to make the UI easier for everyone.

Happy to discuss further offline if you want more of a walk-through on how this might work